# How to do recurring non-sync Windows folder backups to Google drive

Tags: windows, google-drive

The official Google drive application for Windows only supports syncing to drive. I'm looking to instead do recurring separate backups to Google drive. How can I do this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The app will do what it's programmed to do. If it offers a scheduled backup function then it'll be there. So, have you looked for this?